# How do I create a custom header from an existing SSL environment variable?

Tags: mod-rewrite, reverse-proxy, mod-ssl, apache-2.2

OK I have spent all day on this--

I'm using apache with mod_ssl
I'm trying to take an existing environment header, "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s" which looks like "Lastname Firstname Mi username" and set a new header called USERNAME and set that equal to just username (the characters between the last space and the end of the string)

I would then reverse proxy that header to a backend host which would use it to identify the user.

I have tried a lot of different things.  I don't know if the problem is that I don't understand perl regex or if I don't understand the syntax or I'm not putting it in the right place, or all three.

Here is an example of one thing I tried:

```
SetEnvIf SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN (.*\ )(.*) newhostname=$2
RequestHeader set HOSTNAME "%{newhostname}e"
```

All I really want is a new header Hostname to equal the last non-whitespace characters in the DN_CN environment variable.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok -- I figured it out middle of the week but still wanted to give someone a chance to earn the bounty.

Surprisingly, this isn't very well documented anywhere, but as I used mod_headers to do this you can find that documentation [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_headers.html).

What you want to do it **set the header**, whether you grab it from ssl or the environment.  **Then you can edit the header** in place using regex and capture groups.

**Some examples:**

```
  RequestHeader set REMOTE_USER        "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader edit REMOTE_USER (.*\s)(.*) $2
  RequestHeader set AUTHENTICATE_CN    "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader edit AUTHENTICATE_CN (.*\s)(.*) $1
  RequestHeader set AUTHENTICATE_MAIL  "%{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}s"
  RequestHeader edit AUTHENTICATE_MAIL (.*\s)(.*) $2@gmail.com
```

Comment: O_O you bet it's not "well documented", i spend 1h reading the page before getting here, to finally find the %{XX}s syntax !!!

Comment: Yeah it was pretty tough to sort this one out.  I tried probably a dozen things first.  I think though that as mutual auth becomes more prolific, mutating the headers may become more commonplace.  Thanks for the upvote!

Answer (score 1):

I'd use the [AuthBasicFake directive](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_auth_basic.html#authbasicfake) which will set the header and then you can do the [ProxyPass](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) in the same [Location block](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location). It would look something like this:
`<Location "/blah">`
`AuthBasicFake %{SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_CN}`
`ProxyPass http://example.org/blah`
`</Location>`

If you have some other x509 attributes in the subject like the username on its own you could use SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_uid or SSL_CLIENT_S_DN_email.

Comment: I'm specifically trying to pare down to the uid which is part of the dn_cn.  It's not its own x509 attribute otherwise this would be easy.  The username is always the last word in the cn.

Comment: I've had a look and I'm not sure it's possible without an addon module with either AuthBasicFake or <If>/SetEnvIf. Both of these directives use the syntax of the [Apache expr](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html) language where you want the form `variable    ::= "%{" varname "}"
              | "%{" funcname ":" funcargs "}"` but there are no [functions](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/expr.html#functions) which are applicable. The only thing that might work is mod_rewrite.

Answer (score 0):

Never done this with SSL (and I don't really understand it here), but mod_security could be an answer. It can rewrite/add/replace/patch anything inside of decrypted content.